# Remove twist from plank without reducing thickness

Tags: warp, steam-bending

I have a 5/4" x 8" x 6' plank of cherry with a twist on one end. The twist is only about 18" long. When you lay it on a flat surface the corner was raised about 1/4". I tried soaking the board in my hot tube for about 3 hours, (about 130F water). Then I wrapped it in an old blanked, laid it on the garage floor, put a piece of plywood on top of it, and drove over it with the car. I left it there overnight (about 10 hours). This morning I removed the car, unwrapped it, and it's still twisted exactly the same! My next thought is I need hotter water, so I have to come up with a container to soak at least 18" of the board in 212F water, and then try the car again. Any thoughts? Do I need to soak it for a longer time? Or let dry with the car on it for longer? It was still slightly wet when I removed the car this morning.

Comment: You can't be sure the weight of the car is evenly distributed and will make the heated board flat to begin with. Also, when bending wood it's common to over-bend slightly because wood naturally has some springback so you need to shim where needed. If I were doing this first thing I'd try is using your initial heating setup again, with the plank simply clamped down to a workbench (clamps are more than capable of applying the necessary pressure). But as mentioned previously you could easily find in due course that the wood will return to its original twisted shape..

Comment: Another advantage of using clamps as opposed to a large covering surface is that the drying would be more thorough in a shorter time.

Comment: Look up the general concepts of elastic vs. plastic response. Because there will always be some elastic recovery, you need to bend the board beyond flat in order to get it flat in the end. More heat for longer will make that easier/help.

Answer (score 1):

I did a bunch of research but I can't say that you can. Usually with a twisted board you can only joint it flat or cut out what would be useful. I found a question very related to what you asked. The link is below.

[How to straighten a warped board](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/319/how-to-straighten-a-warped-board)